# MapView doesn't ask for location permission

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm trying to build a mapView in Swift. It already worked but after I changed something I can't remember, I'm now getting the following error:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

The `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is in my .plist file.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class AwesomeMap : UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var map: MKMapView?
    var manager: CLLocationManager?

    func setup() {

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager!.delegate = self

        map!.delegate = self // map is being set from another controller

        manager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager!.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        println("permisison did change")
        if(status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
          map!.showsUserLocation = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        for location in (locations as Array) {
            var loc = (location as CLLocation)
            println(loc.coordinate.latitude)

            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: loc.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05))
            map!.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("fail")
    }

}
```

Old code before implementing a few suggestions:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class AwesomeMap : UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var manager = CLLocationManager()
var map: MKMapView?

func setup(mapView: MKMapView) { // passing the IBOutlet from another controller

    // the change I made was around the following six lines I think...

    map = mapView
    map!.delegate = self

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    map!.showsUserLocation = true
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    for location in (locations as Array) {
        var loc = (location as CLLocation)
        println(loc.coordinate.latitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: loc.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05))
        map!.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("fail") // nothing happens here
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're only allowed to call

```
map!.showsUserLocation = true
```

after your Location Manager has got the Permission to use the user Location.

Like in (got no swift version of this, but you'll probably get the point)

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
     if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways)
    {
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah, I got the point, thanks. I implemented it in Swift but actually nothing happens anymore. I'll update my question with the current code.

Comment: @Nikolaj try declaring var manager = CLLocationManager() as a class variable like "var map: MKMapView?" , it probably gets deallocated before the delegate responds.

Comment: Good idea but didn't work as far as I can tell. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Simulator settings

[image: Go to Simulator settings]

after that enter Location Services and turn on . if you need location blue dote in MapView enter <> and set << While Using the App >>

[image: after that enter Location Services and turn on . if you need location blue dote in MapView enter <<YourAppName>> and set << While Using the App >>]

Answer (score 1):

Do not call showsUserLocation when authorization status is undetermined.

```
func setup(mapView: MKMapView) { // passing the IBOutlet from another controller

    map = mapView
    map!.delegate = self

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() // Does not if status is determined.

    self.locationManager(manager: manager, status: CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus())
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .Authorized {
        map!.showsUserLocation = true
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this working code in my app (reduced):

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

additionaly, you can react on any user's authorization status changes:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .Authorized {
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm still getting the same error when I'm using your code.